# String array to print one by one

Tags: php

```
$products = Array ( [products] => Array ( [0] => 12,11,10 [1] => 16,15,14 [2] => 600,103,20 ) );

foreach($products as $k=>$v)
{
    $product_id = $v[0];
    $product_weight_id = $v[1];
    $product_quantity = $v[2];
}
output required like:
12 16 600
11 15 103
10 14 20

current output :
12,11,10 16,15,14 600,103,20
```

Comment: What is $v[x] - array of integers or string with commas? Thanks

Comment: If you just want the spacing - on a browser add `<br />` or PHP_EOL for console output.

Comment: array is string

Comment: but it's only a render problem? because if it is you resolve via css and a little of php. Actually your output is correct

Comment: _“current output :”_ - the code you have shown doesn’t make _any_ output, it is only assigning values to variables.

Comment: yes but pass value in function one by one

Comment: There is no function call anywhere either. Next time you ask such a question, please at least provide a [mre] of what you have.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

If you want to generate a different output, next example may help:

PHP:

```
<?php
$products = array(
    '12,11,10',
    '16,15,14',
    '600,103,20'
);

$output = array();
foreach($products as $product) {
    $a = explode(',', $product);
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
       $output[$key][] = $value; 
    }
}

foreach($output as $line) {
   echo implode(' ', $line)."<br>"; 
}
?>
```

Output:

```
12 16 600 
11 15 103 
10 14 20
```

**Original answer:**

Next example demonstrates two possible approaches to get an output from your array.

PHP:

```
<?php
$products = array(
    '12,11,10',
    '16,15,14',
    '600,103,20'
);

// Complex approach
foreach($products as $product) {
    $a = explode(',', $product);
    foreach ($a as $value) {
       echo $value." "; 
    }
    echo "<br>";
}

// Simple approach
foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product."<br>";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
12 11 10 
16 15 14 
600 103 20 
12,11,10
16,15,14
600,103,20
```

Comment: Good solution, but i think he want to print vertically every sub array

Comment: $products array post data with multiple value to make this string array

Answer (score 1):

Please see below code.

```
$products = array ( 
    '0' => '12,11,10', 
    '1' => '16,15,14', 
    '2' => '600,103,20' 
);

$productIds = array();
$productWeights = array();
$productQuantities = array();

foreach( $products as $k => $v ) {
    $line = explode(',', $v );
    $productIds[] = $line[0];
    $productWeights[] = $line[1];
    $productQuantities[] = $line[2];
}

echo implode( ' ', $productIds);
echo '<br />';
echo implode( ' ', $productWeights);
echo '<br />';
echo implode( ' ', $productQuantities);
echo '<br />';
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `array_map()` and `implode()` you can do it easily. Example:

```
$products = [[12,11,10], [16,15,14], [600,103,20]];
echo implode('<br />', array_map(function ($arr) { return implode(' ', $arr); }, $products));
```

[**Working demo.**](https://3v4l.org/R2tY6)